# Electron-react-boilerplate starts the main process, but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I've just cloned this repo: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate
installed it and tried running it as described in the README file.
But when I run `yarn dev`, the only thing that happens is this: [image]

The electron app doesn't run. Nothing else happens. Am I missing something here? Couldn't find anything else than the `yarn dev` command anywhere on the internet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've managed to resolve this, but I have been having the same problem this evening. Turns out, if you comment out

```
await installExtensions();
```

in the **main.dev.ts** file, then the application will fire up electron in dev mode. Looks like it's hanging at this point.

It's on line 54.

```
const createWindow = async () => {
  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
    process.env.DEBUG_PROD === 'true'
  ) {
    //await installExtensions();
  }
```